# Повысить стабильность работы веб-сайта, основанного на веб-сервисах

Tags: php, http, кэширование, веб-служба, прокси

Задача: обеспечить стабильность работы веб-сайта, основанного на веб-сервисах. Есть интеграция с системами 1С, CRM, другими веб-сайтами по HTTP.

- веб-сервисы могут быть недоступны в течение нескольких часов
- могут отвечать очень долго

Все это приводит к тому, что приходится показывать сообщение "страница временно не доступна".

Как я вижу решение (либо предложите свое): использование промежуточного кеширующего прокси, работающего следующим образом:

- принял требуемый URI
- запросил конечную точку по URI

  - если конечная точка

    - возвращает `20x` / `40x`, передаем назад, для `200` - кешируем
    - возвращает `50x`, взять данные из кеша
    - отвечает более 15 секунд, взять данные из кеша, в фоне обновить кеш
  - все данные, полученные из кеша - помечать каким-либо образом в заголовке, чтобы на веб-сайте можно было вывести сообщение а-ля "показаны данные, актуальные на (дата)"

Сейчас примерно 50 конечных веб-сервисов, поэтому

- нужно какое-то централизованное решение, управляемое, законченное
- основной упор - на решение, а не переделывание архитектуры 50 разделов, эксплуатирующих эти 50 веб-сервисов. проще все свести в одну точку (типа прокси), а не дорабатывать все 50 разделов

Есть варианты, как это сделать? Может быть есть уже готовые решения/демоны/пакеты/сервера для этих целей? Интересует детальное описание методологии / инструментов.

Не подходят такие решения:

- "повышайте доступность внешних сервисов"
- скрипты на PHP, конечно, придется дорабатывать, но вариант "напишите свою либу на PHP" не подходит - я ищу решение другого уровня. хотя... рассмотрю и такой вариант

Comment: Наверно лучше всегда отдавать кеш если он есть и каждый раз в фоне его обновлять. Либо никогда не обновлять а просто удалять его, если было какое-нибудь изменение, чтобы он закешился при след запросе

Comment: @Skywave, на первом хите кеша нет, отдавать нечего.

Comment: Всегда отдавать кеш, греть принудительно и перегревать в зависимости от правил валидации.

Comment: @volcan0, а поподробнее?

Comment: Как это сделано у нас:
1. Есть информация о всех важных ресурсах, скажем,  в виде таблицы
2. Есть демон, который "греет" кеш обращаясь к этим таблицам и запоминает статус (время прогрева, код ответа)
3. Когда кеш протухает - он перегревается демоном заново.
4. Клиенту выдается всегда ответ из кеша

Модифицировать скрипты не придется. Придется писать некий middleware, который выполняется перед отдачей контента. И в нем решать, брать из кеша, брать живой ответ или что-то еще

Comment: @volcan0, решение не подходит по причине того, что список ссылок просто огромный, прогревать кеш невозможно. Некоторые ссылки вообще невозможно заранее предугадать, чтобы поместить в таблицу.

Comment: Не нужен список урлогв, нужен список роутов, причём вы можете собирать их динамически и потом решать их приоритетность.все держать в кеше это абурд.

Comment: Повысить стабильность путём кэширования нельзя. Показывать пользователю устаревшие данные не всегда хорошо. Если сервисы работают очень плохо, то к сайту их нужно подключать асинхронно. И если что-то отвалилось - выводить соответствующее сообщение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, можно сделать кеширующий прокси на `nginx`, для этого есть настройка `proxy_cache_use_stale`.

Выглядит это так:

[image: nginx прокси кеш]

Вот конфиг с моей аннотацией, который можно доработать до собственных нужд:

```
# Настройки кеша
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx   # путь
  levels=1:2                  # количество уровней
  keys_zone=stale_cache:10m   # название:размер зоны, 1Мб ~ 8000 ключей (1 ключ - 1 запрос)
  max_size=10g                # размер данных кеша, при превышении удаляются наиболее старые
  inactive=180m               # время хранения запроса на диске с момента последнего обращения, независимо от Cache-Control
  use_temp_path=off;          # off - используем proxy_cache_path; on - используем proxy_temp_path, указанный в location

server {

  listen                      80;
  error_log                   off;
  access_log                  off;

  # настройки таймаута
  proxy_connect_timeout       10;
  proxy_send_timeout          10;
  proxy_read_timeout          10;
  send_timeout                10;

  # Какой кеш использовать? Инструкцию можно использовать на уровне location
  proxy_cache stale_cache;

  location / {
    # Заголовок:
    #   HIT - из кеша
    #   MISS - с сервера
    #   EXPIRED - время кеширования истекло, взято с сервера
    #   STALE - сервер не отвечает, использовано из кеша
    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

    # Статус бека
    add_header X-Upstream-Status $upstream_status;
    # Как-то надо передавать время, когда было закеширован ответ
    # add_header X-Time ...;

    # Опционально можно игнорировать заголовки:
    # proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie;

    # В некоторых случая можно включить proxy_cache_methods, если данные получаются методом POST (есть случаи)
    # proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;

    # задаем ключ для кэширования @see https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_key
    # можно настроить на уровне сессиий, используя $cookie_jsessionid
    proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$uri$is_args$args;

    # задаем параметры кеширования (минимальное время)
    proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;

    # если нужно минимизировать число обращений к проксированным серверам,
    # выставляем опцию proxy_cache_lock
    # @see https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_lock

    # Если источник "отвалился", будем отдавать с диска
    # updating - в моем случае лучше не использовать, сервер еще не отвалился, но прокси возвращает назад уже результат из кеша со статусом UPDATING
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    # но будем обновляться в фоне - опционально
    # proxy_cache_background_update on;

    # Исключить из кеширования: @see https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_bypass
    # proxy_cache_bypass ...

    # Резолвер (вписан для Докера)
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

    # Куда проксировать - источник данных
    proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
  }

}
```

Что мне не нравится в этом решении:

- много настроек - это с одной стороны хорошо, но получилось очень многословно, для 50 endpoint конфиг распухнет очень серьезно => неудобно администрировать
- при изменении конфига нужно тем или иным способом сбрасывать кеш: либо менять путь, либо `proxy_cache_key`, ни то ни другое не удобно, когда меняешь схему только для одной endpoint, кеш сбросится для всех (либо делать под каждую точку свой конфиг)
- не придумал, как в ответе отдавать время создания кеша, чтобы показывать "данные устарели на ...", вот заголовок `X-Cache-Status` содержит откуда пришли данные (бек, кеш), теперь нужно сделать аналогичное для времени
- вообще я ждал, что есть какие-то более подходящие решения для этих целей - проще конфигурируемые, а если в них будет хоть какая статистика - вообще сказка

PS. Тем кто минусит - пишите причину.

Answer (score 4):

Apache + Nginx(обратный прокси)

Comment: Зачем тут apache? А если Nginx, как его настроить

Comment: @TotalPusher вы указали цель как стабильность сайта, настройки бывают разные, следовательно и ответ общий

Comment: @Slava, я видел одной из опцией некоторых CDN - сайт будет работать даже, если "бек" отвалился. Они каким-то образом кешируют не только статику, но и обычные страницы, которые при нормальной работе бека идут именно с него. Тут ситуация аналогичная.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

- каждое обращение к сторонним ресурсам ставить в очередь на выполнение до тех пор, пока не получен ответ `20x`, либо исчерпан лимит попыток / времени
- каждый ответ `20x` сохранять в кеш / обновлять существующий с обновлением даты / времени
- при задержке ответа сервера более 15 секунд выводить сообщение "страница временно не доступна", а к нему ссылку на сохраненную страницу в кеше с датой / временем

дополнительно:

- собрать статистику часто посещаемых страниц
- написать демона для обновления кеша по расписанию

Comment: В принципе, все верно. Дьявол кроется в деталях. Как ставить в очередь? Какой сервис использовать для кеширования (varnish, memcached, redis, ...)? Как организовать кеш с учетом того, что есть интеграция с разными сервисами - там разные URI, логины-пароли, разное время инвалидации кеша, как этим всем управлять? `написать демона для обновления кеша по расписанию` - как это организовать? есть сервисы, которые получают данные методом POST (да, это плохо, но уж как есть) - опять же интересует что-то большее, чем просто концпепция. дополнил вопрос

Comment: Поясните про бюджет и разработчиков? Есть коммерческие решения?

Answer (score -1):

Тут вам придётся составить шаблон того, что вы описали выше, обернуть все ваши сервисы в абстрактный класс и добавить каждому из них стандартную конфигурацию. Обобщить их всех в архитектурном смысле.

После этого можно использовать к примеру Gearman как очередь задач, где проставлять время time-out для задачи (не-отклика), time-out для вызова сервиса внутри задачи и др. Ну и после этого ждать её окончания или time-out и дальше по расписанному сценарию - либо кэшировать пришедшие данные, либо доставать их из кэша.