# Nginx: настройка кэша

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, кэширование

Пытаюсь настроить кэш на балансировщике с Nginx'ом.
Так чтобы, если отваливается бэкэнд-Apache на сервере с условным сайтом, то балансировщик Nginx начинает отдавать сайт из кэша.
Попытался реализовать таким способом прочитав документацию Nginx, но ничего не вышло. Папка с кэшем создаётся, но он в неё складывает горсть каких-то огрызков и при отключении бекэнд-Apache (вручную для теста) ничего не отдаётся и сайт ложится с 502 ошибкой. Что может быть некорректно настроено?

Директива в блоке http в основном конфигурационном файле nginx.conf:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:32m max_size=1g 
                 inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
```

Директивы в дополнительном конфигурационном файле conf.d/hostinng.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.ru www.domain.ru;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://ip_address:port;
        proxy_cache cache;
        proxy_cache_revalidate on;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502
                              http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_background_update on;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
    }
}
```

Весь основной конфиг nginx'а:

```
    user nginx;
    worker_processes 1;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

    include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

    events {
        worker_connections 1024;
    }
    http {
        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$host" "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        sendfile            on;
        tcp_nopush          on;
        tcp_nodelay         on;
        keepalive_timeout   30;
        keepalive_requests  100;
        client_body_timeout 10;
        send_timeout 2;
        reset_timedout_connection on;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript 
        text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

        client_max_body_size 5m;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=all:32m max_size=1g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;

        default_type        application/octet-stream;
        server {
            listen       80 default_server;
            server_name  default.testserver.ru;
        location / {
            return 404;
        }
            error_page 404 /404.html;
                location = /40x.html {
            }
            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                location = /50x.html {
            }
        }

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Вывод nginx -T:

```
    # configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$host" "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
#Timeout for keep-alive connections. Server will close connnections after this time.
    keepalive_timeout   30;
#Max amount of requsts a client can make during one one keep-alive connection.
    keepalive_requests  100;
    client_body_timeout 10;
    send_timeout 2;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
#    types_hash_max_size 2048; 

#Zhatie trafica c perechislennimi tipami
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;   

#Cashirovanie cachsto ispolzuemih filov i ih udalenie iz cache
#    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
#    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
#    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
#    open_file_cache_errors on;

    client_max_body_size 5m;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;


     proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=all:32m max_size=1g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
#    map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
#   default         off;
#   text/html       max;
#   text/css        max;
#   aplication/javascript   max;
#   ~image/         max;
#}

    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  default.testserver.ru;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
        return 404;
    }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl default_server;
#        server_name  default.testserver.ru;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#        location / {
#            return 404;
#        }
#   }

     # Load configuration files for the default server block.
     include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}


# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-perl.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-mail.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_mail_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-stream.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so";

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;

    text/mathml                                      mml;
    text/plain                                       txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor                 jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                                 wml;
    text/x-component                                 htc;

    image/png                                        png;
    image/svg+xml                                    svg svgz;
    image/tiff                                       tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                               wbmp;
    image/webp                                       webp;
    image/x-icon                                     ico;
    image/x-jng                                      jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                                   bmp;

    font/woff                                        woff;
    font/woff2                                       woff2;

    application/java-archive                         jar war ear;
    application/json                                 json;
    application/mac-binhex40                         hqx;
    application/msword                               doc;
    application/pdf                                  pdf;
    application/postscript                           ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                                  rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl                    m3u8;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml             kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz                 kmz;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                         xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject                    eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                    ppt;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics      odg;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  odp;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet   ods;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text          odt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                     pptx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                     xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                     docx;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc                         wmlc;
    application/x-7z-compressed                      7z;
    application/x-cocoa                              cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff                  jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file                     jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                           run;
    application/x-perl                               pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                              prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed                     rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager             rpm;
    application/x-sea                                sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash                    swf;
    application/x-stuffit                            sit;
    application/x-tcl                                tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert                       der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall                          xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                            xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                             xspf;
    application/zip                                  zip;

    application/octet-stream                         bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream                         deb;
    application/octet-stream                         dmg;
    application/octet-stream                         iso img;
    application/octet-stream                         msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                                       mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                                       mp3;
    audio/ogg                                        ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                                      m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                                ra;

    video/3gpp                                       3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                                       ts;
    video/mp4                                        mp4;
    video/mpeg                                       mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                                  mov;
    video/webm                                       webm;
    video/x-flv                                      flv;
    video/x-m4v                                      m4v;
    video/x-mng                                      mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                                   asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                                   wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                                  avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/hosting.conf:

#    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=all:32m max_size=1g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name testsite.ru www.testsite.ru;
    location / {
        return 301 https://testsite.ru$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name testsite.ru www.testsite.ru;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
#       set_real_ip_from 10.128.6.104;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#       real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
#       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
#   ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/testsite.ru/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/testsite.ru/cert.key;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.ru www.domain.ru;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
        proxy_cache all;
        proxy_cache_revalidate on;
#       proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_background_update on;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
#       proxy_cache_valid 10m;
#       proxy_cache_lock on;
#       expires $expires;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
#   location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|htc|html|php|css|js|rss)$ {
#       expires 1d;
#       add_header Cache-Control "public";
#   }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте `proxy_pass` перенести в конец. Вообще [вот мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/994988/287469) на аналогичный свой вопрос. И [репо](https://github.com/dbfun/nginx-cached-proxy) где я ставил эксперименты

Comment: А что ещё показать? Конфиг Nginx'а или Apache?

Comment: @Total Pusher Переместил **proxy_pass**. Также прописал директиву **proxy_cache_min_uses 1** - всё это не помогло.

Comment: @TotalPusher добавил

Comment: @TotalPusher добавил

Comment: `nginx -T` T - заглавная, эта опция собирает весь конфиг воедино

Comment: @TotalPusher исправил

Comment: добавьте в `location` где кеширование это: `proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie; proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;`

Comment: @TotalPusher спасибо, помогло!

Comment: `если отваливается бэкэнд-Apache на сервере с условным сайтом, то балансировщик Nginx начинает отдавать сайт из кэша`. на самом деле даже если бек работает, отдается из кеша. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dbfun/nginx-cached-proxy/master/assets/nginx.gif Там где HIT - из кеша, EXPIRED - с бека, STALE - из кеша (бек отвалился). Как я не пробовал это поправить, с Nginx не получилось. Со Squid - получилось. Varnish по идее также можно заставить работать, в сети есть инструкции, но ни одна из них не работает с последней версией варниша. Зато у варниша шикарная документация на счет кеширования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря @TotalPusher проблема решена. 
Не хватало директивы  запрещающей обработку некоторых полей заголовка - proxy_ignore_headers. Также была некорректно настроена директива proxy_cache_valid.